# How to prevent iOS merging contacts with the same name

Tags: ios, contacts

I want to add a new contact. Let's say all I have is the first name "Joe" and a phone number. How do I do that without iOS stupidly linking the phone number to an existing "Joe" I have in my contacts list. This UX as it seems to work right now is frustrating.

Comment: I just did it on 14.6 without a problem.  I see two entries for 'Joe', each with their own phone number.  What iOS version are you using and what steps are you following, exactly, to add the names?

Comment: I avoid that possibility by putting “Joe B” and “Joe M” and “Joe S” etc

Comment: @fsb It may be because I am also using a Gmail account on my phone? I'm on the latest iOS. I just create a new contact with a first name and phone number

Comment: I don't think gmail has anything to do with the Contacts app adding contacts, but I could be wrong.  I can create several 'first name, phone number' contacts without a problem.  Please [edit] your question with the steps you're taking, exactly.  If you have screenshots of the problem, that might help, too.